# How to exclude a specific two digit number (happens to be "12")?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

This is Google Analytics regex by the way.

I want to exclude the number "8" and the number "12" (twelve) from matching.

This is the best I could come up with so far, but it's not correct:

```
[^((12)|8)]
```

This, according to regexpal.com still excludes 1, 2, and 8—rather than 12 and 8.

**EDIT:** To answer the comments below my question, the data will always be in the form of either a single or two-digit number (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ..., 99). It's definitely not critical that the expression be filtered for numbers only however, as I would never expect to see any other kind of data but this going into this field.

Comment: PS - When I say "Google Analytics regex", I mean that negative lookaheads (and possibly some other advanced regex features) can't be used. At least, that's what I understand! Thanks. :)

Comment: describe all numbers that are not 8 and 12

Comment: @Drewdavid: Please post sample data in which you are matching numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any number (integer) except 8 and 12, a possible pattern is:

```
[02-79][0-9]*|8[0-9]+|1([013-9][0-9]*|2[0-9]+)?
```

*(Note that this is not the shortest, but alternatives are sorted by probability.)*

But if you use this pattern alone with a string that contains 12, it will succeed, matching only the 1 (or the 2). To solve the problem, your pattern must be anchored.

**Anchors**

Two possibilities:

1) You are testing if a whole string is a number:

In this case, you can complete your expression using start and end of the string anchors:

```
^([02-79][0-9]*|8[0-9]+|1([013-9][0-9]*|2[0-9]+)?)$
```

2) You are testing if a string contains a number:

Most of the time, other regex engines use a word-boundary `\b` to do that, but according to [this document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en), it seems that this feature isn't available. So the workaround consists to describe all possible scenarios on the left and on the right of the pattern:

```
([^0-9]|^)([02-79][0-9]*|8[0-9]+|1([013-9][0-9]*|2[0-9]+)?)([^0-9]|$)
```

where `[^0-9]|^` means a character that isn't a digit or the start of the string. *(same thing for the end)*

Comment: thanks for sharing your answer! This seems to check out in my testing tools, now to see if it will work for Google Analytics!

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what you are trying to do by regex `[^((12)|8)]`. Here you have declared inside *character class* match **anything except** `(` `)` `|` `1` `2` `8`. So every instance of those characters will be discarded.

**[Result of `[^((12)|8)]`](https://regex101.com/r/nY3aY1/1)**

---

To not to match `12` and `8` you will have to specify what you want to match.

**Regex:** `\b([02-9][0-9]|[0-9][013-9]|[0-79])\b`

**Explanation:**

- `\b` on both sides set word boundary to match only numbers.
- `[02-9][0-9]` matches all numbers except `1` preceded by `2` i.e `12`.
- `[0-9][013-9]` matches all numbers except `2` succeeded by `1` i.e `12`
- `[0-79]` matches all numbers except `8`.
- `|` alteration used to match any of the cases.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wU0jK4/4)**

Comment: Thanks @noob this is cool! I made a discovery while doing some testing that this also seems to exclude the number "18" as well! At least, according to regexpal.com. I only tested up to "50".

Comment: @Drewdavid: Oh ! I made a silly mistake in regex. Updated answer now. Should check. I corrected the second alteration from `[0-9][0137-9]` to `[0-9][013-9]`. That's why It wasn't matching `8` at units place.

Comment: Thanks noob. I'm upvoting this answer but for now accepting @Casimir et Hippolyte's due to the ambiguous treatment of the `\b` feature by Google Analytics! Maybe I will find this out and update the question. I would upvote it twice if I could because of the useful explanation. :)